# What is the minimum necessary code to keep a session alive in classic ASP?

Tags: session, asp-classic, session-timeout, keep-alive

I have a classic ASP site that I would like the sessions to stay alive as long as the user has a page open. So I used some Javascript to periodically call a 'keepalive' ASP page to keep the session alive so the timeout is not reached.

What do I need to put in the ASP page code to make sure it renews the session timer? Can it be a blank page or do I need to hit the Session object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524798%28VS.90%29.aspx):

> A session automatically ends if a user has not requested or refreshed
>   a page in an application for a specified period of time.

Based on that description, I don't think it matters what's in your "keepalive" script, as long as the request is made.

Comment: All sessions will be killed when the Application Pool recycles, so check the settings in IIS as the defaults are set to recycle after a certain number of requests or a period of time.  You can configure it to recycle at specific times of day (say during your quietest period) so that fewer users are affected.

Answer (score 1):

I use a small inline frame at the bottom of a page to do this in admin sessions where the user is editing conent. All that's in the frame page is a meta refresh that fires every 5 minutes to keep the session alive. Works great.

Comment: This solution didn't work in case user may close their browser

Comment: That's how sessions work. They are meant to be temporary, and won't persist if the browser is not active.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that as long as you perform some kind of server process periodically, the session doesn't end.

What I do is have a javascript function that is periodically run via a setInterval() function call in the onLoad process of the  tag.

In that function I execute a server-side SQL query.

I place this inside the  section with all of javascript and styleshooe loads:

Then I place the following lines right after my  tag:

-->
RSEnableRemoteScripting("."); -->